# How to store device info in shared preference in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, store, device, flutter-dependencies

in this question i want to store device info into shared preferences becuase i want to access device info anywhere from application. Hope you understand the question. your small help can made my day :)

Here is some code i've tried

```
      Future deviceinfo() async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
          print("Hey Android User");
          print('Running on ${androidInfo.id}');
          print('Running on ${androidInfo.isPhysicalDevice}');
          print('Running on ${androidInfo.fingerprint}');
//Here in this line error
          SharedPreferences devicepref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          devicepref.setString('deviceinfo', androidInfo);
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
          print("Hey IOS User");
          print('Running on ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}');
        }
      }
```

Comment: declare variable outside the `deviceinfo()` then set the variable

Comment: can you please help me to do this. if you can please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Save your info in memory, set sharedprefs using :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
          prefs.setString('deviceinfo', androidInfo.id});
          prefs.setString('deviceID', your_android_id_value});
          prefs.setString('deviceName', your_android_name_value});
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
          prefs.setString('deviceinfo', iosInfo.utsname.machine});
          prefs.setString('deviceID', your_ios_id_value});
          prefs.setString('deviceName', your_ios_name_value});
        }
```

To get info from memory using shared prefs :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     String info=prefs.getString("deviceinfo");
     String info=prefs.getString("deviceID");
     String info=prefs.getString("deviceName");
     print("info : ${info}");
     print("ID: ${deviceID}");
     print("Name: ${deviceName}");
```

This will help you.